# Delete part of memory mapped file

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

#### How can i delete only some portion of a memory mapped file ?

Lets say a have a file with one int, one long and a string with 20 characters:

```
[ 4  ][    8   ][         20         ]

[IIII][LLLLLLLL][SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS]
```

I´m tring to put empty byte arrays in place of the data, but the data is replaced by null, and not ripped of as I would like.

Heres my code:

```
RandomAccessFile memoryMappedFile = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt", "rw");
FileChannel fc = memoryMappedFile.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mem = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 32);
int num = mem.getInt();
long val = mem.getLong();
byte[] strByte = new byte[20];
String str = mem.get(strByte);

// tring to erase
byte[] EMPTY_INT  = new byte[4];
byte[] EMPTY_LONG = new byte[8];
byte[] EMPTY_STR; = new byte[20];
mem.setPosition(0);
mem.putInt(EMPTY_INT);
mem.putLong(EMPTY_LONG);
mem.put(EMPTY_STR);
```

I want that after this operation the block just go away, and not to be empty.

Comment: it's just a file. if you want to delete part of a file, you need to do the operations that make it happen: 1) copy the first part of the file you still want 2) skip the part you want to delete 3) copy the rest of the file you want to keep, so your file goes from IIILLLSSS to IIISSS. If you null/zero out the middle parts, you don't "delete" anything, you're just overwriting: III000SSS

Comment: @MarcB:  except this is a memory-mapped file, so normal file operations don't really apply.

Comment: you'd need to truncate the actual file afterwards. memmap is a 1:1 mapipng between ram and the file's contents. if you want to shrink the memory region, you'll have to shrink the file.